# Proof logical statement with interference rules

Tags: proof-verification, logic, formal-proofs

## Proof following statement with interference rules ( without truth table) that

$$ (\neg C \wedge B \wedge (A \rightarrow C) \wedge (B \rightarrow D ) )\implies (\neg A \wedge D ) $$

## Attempt to proof

1. $B$ (premise)
2. $B \rightarrow D$ (premise)
3. $D$ (Modus ponens 1,2)
4. $A \rightarrow C $ (premise)
5. $\neg C$ (premise)
6. $\neg A$ (Modus tollens 5,4)
7. $\neg A \wedge D$ (Conjunction introduction 6, 3)

   ---

   Q.E.D

Is my proof correct?

Comment: your statement is missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: @J.W.Tanner What do you mean by this?

Comment: The first $($ is extraneous

Comment: the statement has 4 '('s but only 3 ')'s

Comment: Yes that would be typo, I'll fix that

Comment: Since the $\Rightarrow$ is the meta-logical symbol for logical implication, rather than a logical operator (such as $\to$), you actually don't need that outside set of parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You really have only one premise:

$$ \neg C \wedge B \wedge (A \rightarrow C) \wedge (B \rightarrow D )$$

Thus, you'll need to *infer* the statements that you have on lines 1,2,4, and 5 from this premise using the Simp rule (this is short for Simplification ... other textbooks call this conjunction elimination)

Also, for line 7, the name of the rule in your system is Conj (short for Conjunction) ... you call this conjunction introduction, and indeed many textbooks do, but in your system it is Conj

Otherwise, your proof looks to be fine!

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Good point (assuming this is what you mean): I can't be certain until the OP lets us know exactly what inference rules need to be used ... edited my answer

Comment: @Bram28 the exact rules I was suppose to use are here. https://i.imgur.com/qVTimfL.png, It's in Finnish but you can probably understand it.

Comment: @Tuki Thanks!  So yes, the rule of inferring a conjunct from a conjunction is called Simp. (also, in your system the rule to conjunct together any number of claims is called Conj, rather than Conjunction Introduction))